# How to Limit Download Speeds from my Website on my IIS Windows Server?

Tags: iis, webserver

When people download files from my website, I don't want them to be able to download faster than 300KB/sec per file.

Is there anyway to do this? I'm running IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 5):

You can't limit download speed but you can limit the overall traffic to a particular website:

1. Open IIS MMC
2. Select Website
3. Select Performance tab
4. Enable 'Bandwidth throttling'

Answer (score 2):

Write a script that transfer the data in chunks. After 300KB you wait until 1 seconds is consumed.

Comment: That doesn't really throttle the bandwidth. The 300KB chunk will still download at the fastest rate possible. If You multiply that by X users, even with a 1s delay between chunks it isn't going to have the desired effect.

Comment: How I understand the question this should limit per user. If I send only 300KB per seconds then in middle there will be only 300KB transfer rate for this user.

Comment: No what you have is a burst of data at the max available bandwith then a delay then another burst of data at max speed again. This isn't really bandwidth throttling.

Comment: You will have to make the pause very much smaller, I think, so it goes "fine", like tracing a circle with PI. Beginning it's very edged, and the edges get finer and finer until it looks like a circle.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this but I haven't had time to try it out myself [IIS Bit Rate Throttlling](http://www.iis.net/download/BitRateThrottling)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Horcrux (cant vote it as dont have enough rep)

if the file is less than 300KB, then this wont work,
but for large files, then adverage over the course of the whole file download will be 
300Kbps...

I'm assuming the idea is like a rapidshare idea, premium users will have full speed downloads?

Also, while one thread(user) is waiting for a second, another thread can be downloading.

Queue the downloads, and only let X amount run at the same time, and your away in a hack!

Answer (score 0):

Within website properties in IIS 6.0 there is a Performance tab and the first setting is Bandwith throttling which allows you to set the maximum bandwidth value in kilobytes per second. It also has this note;

*For bandwidth throttling to function, IIS needs to install Windows Packet Scheduler.*

I'm guessing using this setting would mean having your downloads on a separate site so you can throttle that but maintain full bandwidth to your normal content.

Answer (score 0):

For IIS 10, go to IIS Manager and you will find a your setting under the header

Media Services > Bit Rate Throttling

[image]

Answer (score -7):

Reduce the speed of you Internet connection.