# Sleep function is IIS

Tags: php, iis

I write the php code in iis to serve file for download with speed limit, so i need to use sleep function for the speed limit.

Here, few lines of my code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
while(!feof($file))
{
    echo fread($file, 1024*10);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
    if (connection_status()!=0)
    {
        @fclose($file);
        exit;
    }

}
```

But the browser say: 'Waiting for mysite'. If i remove `sleep(1)` everything is right. I also test in apache and everything is right too.

So I have a problem in IIS with the sleep function.

Comment: A better question is why are you using `sleep(1);` ?

Comment: @Steven I want to limit speed to 10kb per second

Comment: Shouldn't you set this in the web server instead? For example by using the Bit rate throttling extension http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/bit-rate-throttling

Comment: @JohnP I want to first authenticating user then send file, and need to do it in php

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your server properly configured for that. TBH you should use something on the server to do that, rather then relying on PHP, the `sleep(1);` causes it to send a chunk, pause, send a chunk pause, etc. It does not maintain 10kbps but goes from like 500kbps for a second to 0 kbps for a second, it may average out to 10kbps, but it is not the same and some programs won't treat it correct and may terminate the download. You should look into QoS ([How to Limit Download Speeds from my Website on my IIS Windows Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130034/how-to-limit-download-speeds-from-my-website-on-my-iis-windows-server))

Comment: it isn't sent anything ! it just say waiting for replay and after about 10 min say connection timeout, i want to use it from php

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem with IIS? Note that waiting for 1 second will mean that your script may exceed the timeout limit (this can be as low as 30 seconds) so IIS will kill your script.

If you want to serve large files, I recommend serving them directly from IIS and using IIS' built-in rate limiter rather than via PHP.

See here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits

Comment: No. i use `set_time_limit(0);` , and the server is loading and don't get timeout.